# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.TypesImpl.getType

Tags: jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, glassfish, glassfish-3

My Web Container is GlassFish Server 3+, when I run my Java application, the application will be ran correctly but I see the following error in my console.

```
INFO: The Admin Console is already installed, but not yet loaded.
SEVERE: Exception while visiting java/lang/Object.class of size 1515
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.TypesImpl.getType(TypesImpl.java:78)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.ModelClassVisitor.visit(ModelClassVisitor.java:119)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:348)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:70)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:307)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:296)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start your server without a deployment task, do you get these errors??

These errors are related to internal glassfish server classes. When I started learning GF, my internship master has told me that these kind of errors are related to bugs, especially the errors that appear when you try to stop gf server.

Good luck.